# Weird result when reading from /dev/ttyS0 in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, serial-port

I try to send a command to an hardware and want to grab the result back. I am sure that when I send a command like: `echo "read" > /dev/ttyS0`, the command will be executed. The problem comes up while grabbing the feedback. For that, I want to use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "READ" > /dev/ttyS0

#stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -echo

STR="result "

while read -r -s -t 1 -n 1 c && [[ $c != '>' ]]
do
    STR+=$c
done < /dev/ttyS0

echo $STR
```

The result should something like that.

```
Level 0
001,001, 002,002;>
```

But when I execute the script, sometimes I get the right result, but most times I get nothing back.

Comment: Maybe the timeout is too short? Check what the 'read' command returns. If the code is more than 128 then it's timeout.

Comment: `read -r -t 20 -d '>' STR < /dev/ttyS0` might be simpler; that output doesn't look like something that is going to trickle in one byte at a time.

Comment: Timeout was not the problem and the shorter suggestion are also not working as well.

Comment: What I manged to get working is, that i get back the command i Send. `Script: #!/bin/bash

command="read"
interface="/dev/ttyS0"

echo "Send '$command' to router ($interface)"

stty -F $interface 9600
stty -F $interface  raw
stty -F $interface  -echo
stty -F $interface min 100 time 100

echo $command > $interface

#read -r -t 2 -d '>' STR < /dev/ttyS0

while read -r -s -t 1 -n 1 c && [[ $c != '>' ]]
do
 STR+=$c
 #echo $c
done < /dev/ttyS0

echo "result: $STR"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this script:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyS0',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
    )

    str=""
    c=""
    ser.write("terminal off\r\n")
    ser.readline();
    ser.write("read\r\n")

    while (len(str) < 2 or c != ">"):
        c = ser.readline()
        str += c    

    ser.close()

    print(str)
```